# NGINX: Rewrite using http without redirection

Tags: http, redirect, nginx, url-rewriting

Stackoverflowers,
I need to create a reverse proxy which points to http://example.com, but instead of redirecting it to the site I need to rewrite it, without changing the URL. The IP of my nginx reverse proxy is http://10.31.0.147/. 
Unfortunatelly, my current configuration is not working:

```
server {
        listen 80 default_server;
        listen [::]:80 default_server;
        location / {
        rewrite ^/$ http://example.com break;
        proxy_redirect off;
 }
}
```

If I remove http:// from rewrite command I'm getting error "404 Not Found" If I leave it as it is, I'm getting redirected and the URL is changed to www.example.com. Is there a way to workaround this and not change http://10.31.0.147. In the NGINX documentation I've read that whenever I use "http://" the page is getting redirected.

Comment: Why not use proxy_pass?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of using rewrite, I've used proxy pass

```
    location / {
       proxy_pass   https://example.com;
       proxy_set_header X-Real-IP example.com;
       proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For example.com;
       proxy_set_header Host example.com;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

It's simple:

```
location / {
  proxy_pass https://$server_name$request_uri;
  proxy_http_version 1.1;
  proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
  proxy_set_header Connection $connection_upgrade;
  proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
  proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
  proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
  proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Port $server_port;
}
```